# Is there a way to manage multiple versions of an image in one PSD file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Sometimes I need to have multiple versions of a similar piece of work in Photoshop (CC 2018). (Such as a large logo, and a much smaller slightly different design of the same logo)

To save time and preserve common features of the two versions I create version 2 from version 1.

To preserve version one I do a save-as and create a new PSD file.

I was wondering if there is a feature within Photoshop to manage both versions within one PSD file.  I believe there was/is something along these lines in Adobe Fireworks.

I have had a look around photoshop and I can't find anything (apart from manually copying all the layers and grouping them)

Comment: Have you looked into Smart Objects?

Comment: Take a look at this design versioning [tools](https://blog.prototypr.io/design-versioning-its-true-it-s-here-let-s-talk-and-learn-more-about-it-9fef5d7cb517)